# Unable to activate susy-2.1.1, because sass-3.2.17 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, susy-compass, susy-sass

I have installed the latest versions of compass, sass and susy. But still I am getting this error:

```
Unable to activate susy-2.1.1, because sass-3.2.17 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)
```

Anyone knows how this Ruby thing works?

This is the list of my installed gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

CFPropertyList (2.2.0)
chunky_png (1.3.0)
compass (0.12.4)
compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.19)
compass-import-once (1.0.4)
compass-rails (1.1.3)
fssm (0.2.10)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
multi_json (1.9.2)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rubygems-update (2.2.2)
sass (3.3.4, 3.3.3, 3.2.17)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
susy (2.1.1)
```

Comment: I'm not a Ruby dev, but it sounds like you need to uninstall sass 3.2.17.

Comment: Sounds logical. I'll try installing a previous version

Comment: No luck:( Tried the bundler method but the error still remain. Can't get susy to work so I'm going to use another grid system

Comment: To use Bundler first type 'bundle init' in Terminal at the desired directory.That will write a basic Gemfile. Load the Gemfile into nano and add in the items you want just as I have written below. Save the Gemfile. Then still in the same directory in Terminal type 'bundle install'. It should work but occasionally terminal asks you to install such and such a dependency first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Bundler, it will ensure that the gems in your Gemfile are the ones used by your project. So your Gemfile should specify "susy", "~>2.1.1" and "sass", "~>3.3.2", plus any other that you require, such as "breakpoint", "~>2.4.1". It then won't matter what versions are installed inside your Ruby gems folder. When you then do a 'bundle install', Bundler ensures that your project will only use the correct dependencies. This is, of course, a CLI instruction through the terminal. Alternatively, simply do a 'sudo gem uninstall sass -v 3.2.17', if you don't want to use Bundler.

Comment: Quick start guide to use Bundler: http://ruby.about.com/od/bundler/ss/Getting-Started-With-Bundler.htm

Comment: The last suggestion (uninstall sass -v 3.2.17) is not possible. If I try that I get the error "If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.) Continue with Uninstall [yN]".

Comment: Re the error 'if you uninstall ... etc.", it doesn't matter. Just re-install sass -v 3.3.0 and the correct dependencies will be added.

Answer (score 10):

`gem install compass --pre`

if you ended up uninstalling the  sass 3.3.0 gem you should reinstall that first.

Comment: Yes, Susy 2 requires Sass 3.3. In order to use Compass with Sass 3.3, you need to use the Compass pre-release.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you will also need to install ruby1.9.1-dev package, or you will get this error: 'require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)

Answer (score 5):

The best way without a doubt is to install Susy via the Compass Susy Plugin. This will avoid conflicts with other Compass projects that require the current version.

Commands:

```
gem install compass
gem install compass-susy-plugin
```

Comment: This totally solve the issue for me on first attempt after spending a lot of time on other workarounds. Thanks Simon!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu server 14.04 and I had the same problem and this is what I have done

- Remove all my gems with `gem uninstall gemname`
- Install bundler with `sudo apt-get install bundler`
- Create a Gemfile as @Remy said before. Here is a Getting Started With Bundler Guide
- And finally `bundle install`

After that, bundler create a Gemfile.lock where are specified all the needed gems and its versions, so you can use it safely.

Answer (score 0):

https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/cant-make-susy-211-working

User: Iago Wandalsen Prates

gem uninstall compass

gem uninstall sass

gem uninstall susy

gem install susy

gem install compass --pre