# cannot create a new compass project with susy

Tags: ruby, macos, sass

i am using ruby 2.1 via rbenv to run compass on osx.

in order to create a new compass project as instructed on the [website](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/command-line/), i executed the following:

```
bash-3.2$ compass create v2layout -r susy -u susy
```

then i get this message:

```
Gem::LoadError on line ["2064"] of /Users/au/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb: Unable to activate susy-2.1.1, because sass-3.2.18 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Not sure what is going on here.  I would need to have susy package installed since the project's scss is going to need to "@import susy" but susy always installs conflicting sass version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to activate susy-2.1.1, because sass-3.2.17 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576123/unable-to-activate-susy-2-1-1-because-sass-3-2-17-conflicts-with-sass-3-3-0)

Comment: thanks @EricMSuzanne, i uninstalled the previous version of compass and all versions of sass, then installed the pre-release of compass and got this:
`bash-3.2$ gem install compass --pre
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/ffi-1.0.12.pre-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz)`

Comment: @EricMSuzanne, not sure what that previous error was about.  i re-ran the installation and it succeeded.  may have been a patchy WAN connection.  thanks for your help, and for susy!