# Add Susy to existing grunt build

Tags: susy-sass, breakpoint-sass

I have an existing project that I build with grunt and would like to add Susy. The build works fine without Susy.

It looks like Breakpoint should be used with Susy. Both of these require Sass to be at least V3.3. And from the CLI it is: Sass 3.3.10 (Maptastic Maple).

I used Gem Compass to get the latest version of Compass (Compass 0.12.6). But it uses (and installed) a version of sass (sass-3.2.19.gem) that is incompatible with Susy and Breakpoint.

After adding Susy to the Compass task in grunt, I get:

Gem::LoadError on line ["2064"] of /home/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb: Unable to activate susy-2.1.2, because sass-3.2.19 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)

I would like to minimize my use of Ruby. This project does not have have a config.rb. (That means that I would prefer not to get a solution like "Use Bundler".)

I figure I must be missing something basic.

Answer (score 1):

I kept looking for a solution after posting the question, and eventually decided to try Compass alpha version. With a couple of caveats, that got things working.

Install the latest alpha Compass (from [Unable to activate susy-2.1.1, because sass-3.2.17 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576123/unable-to-activate-susy-2-1-1-because-sass-3-2-17-conflicts-with-sass-3-3-0)) and 
[breakpoint-sass Install Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142627/breakpoint-sass-install-issue)

```
$ gem install compass --pre
```

This link got me to decide it was safe to use the alpha version: https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/350

This may not impact others with this issue, but FYI...

The new Compass version causes warnings in normalize https://github.com/JohnAlbin/normalize.css-with-sass-or-compass
which is now https://github.com/JohnAlbin/normalize-scss
where there is a new version.

```
/* normalize-scss 3.0.0-alpha.2+normalize.3.0.0 | MIT/GPLv2 License | bit.ly/normalize-scss */
```

The new _normalize.scss fixed the warning. I just copied the one file, no installation.

Compass 1.0...alpha also causes problems with Bourbon. I was already using the current version of Bourbon, 4.0.1, and what I'm seeing is already a reported Issue: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/456
Very strange that the notes say that the version I was already using required Sass 3.3.x.